# Using dependencies properties yml vs .yaml springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have 2 projects, a `db-sdk` project which has all the models and repositories, and the db properties file (application.yml), and is a dependency of the project `db-api`.
In `db-api` i want to use `db-sdk`'s properties from it's `application.yml` file, but for some reason it works only with `.yaml` or `.properties` extensions, if i use `.yml`, the default properties for the db are used.
Why is it so? isn't yaml and yml the same?

Comment: SpringBoot uses application.properties or application.yml, I don't think `.yaml` is ever considered

Comment: I've always used .yml aswell, but for some reason it just does not work in this case.

Comment: Is there another `.yml` in the `db-api` project?

Comment: Theres only 1 application.yml file, there is another redisson-config.yml in a subdirectory, which is referenced in the application.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this happens because you can't have 2 application.yml files with the same name, so it ignores the second one. With other extensions it is not considered the same file name so it works.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [website](https://betamax.software/2021/11/yaml-vs-yml-whats-the-difference/): "The .yaml and .yml are both extensions of YAML (YAML Ain’t Markup Language). Both offer similar interpretations and syntax. However, questions about their differences are piling up, and some users are confused about which one to use. The major difference between the two is that the older versions of Windows only allowed three letters in the extension, such as .yml. Meanwhile, the OS system now doesn’t have restrictions for the number of letters. That’s why some users prefer .yaml.

On the other hand, there are yaml users who like to write faster. Thus, they pick .yml since it has fewer characters, the extension is 25% faster to write. Some users say that the Extensions do not have a bearing at all on the content. The only consideration is those Windows Programs that still have restrictions on the number of characters and they opt to limit the characters into three alone.

Generally, YAML creators prefer users to use the new 4-character extension (.yaml) since most Operating Systems allow more than three characters in the text document. However, programmers still use the (.yml) because it is faster to write. Another difference between the two extensions is Docker commonly uses .yml while Kubernetes’ documents .yaml."